# Idle Worker Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

could anyone please let me know what is the importance of Idle worker in Apache stats, I see many of them (is it possible to reduce its timeout)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apache configuration is sometimes like this: it creates a lot of "workers" that are idle=waiting for an incoming connexion. As soon as someone makes a request and the web server handles it, it takes one "free" worker = "idle worker" and gives it the connexion. So, depending on your configuration, your may have a "fixed" number of workers, or a variable number of workers in what's called a pool ("a pool of workers").
Checkout [Apache MPM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html)